# SetCookie in javascript does not work on mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, cookies

The below javascript code sets cookies from a web browser. However, when i try to do the same from my mobile browser(iOs,Andriod) it would just not work ? When i try to read the cookie it would display as blank.

So for some reason the set cookies does not work on mobile browser but does on web browser? I am not sure why can someone help ?

```
var usrnm = "xyz@gmail.com";
var cookievalue= usrnm + ";";
document.cookie="ck_dp_email=" + cookievalue;
```

Also, is there any substitute to cookies on mobile browser ? I tried local storage but i found the behavior on different pages to be different it would work on some page some not. All i want to do is set the emailid and read it on diffrent pages on mobile browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have cookies enabled in your mobile browser? If yes, then how are you trying to read the cookie?